# Connect to azure SQL Database through whitelisted Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I want to connect to client's Azure SQL Database using specific range of IP address **through** `whitelisted` IP address of `Azure Virtual Machine`.

**What I already have is**:

- access to whitelisted azure virtual machine
- able to connect through that `Azure VM`

**Issue I'm facing in**:

- Connecting to client's Azure SQL DB using my organization machine which is not whitelisted but have access to that whitelisted VM.

Can **Gateway Connection** feature of Power BI service can help me?

[image: Use an On-premises or VNet data gateway]

Answer (score 0):

Your client needs to allow your organization machine IP address to connect to the database and it should be done from the server ip firewall setting. you can not connect directly by using your whitelisted vm. Please check this for [IP firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure)

Comment: Yes, I've checked that but I was wondering if **Gateway connection** feature of Power BI service can help in any possible way. I have updated the question for the same.

Comment: No you can not connect. Data gateway act as bridge between your onprem data source and powerBI. it allows  Allows multiple users  or user to connect to multiple on-premises data sources. With a single gateway installation

Comment: There are two types of data gateways onprem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/   and vnet data gateway https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/vnet/overview

Comment: Yes that's right, I tried connecting with basic authentication but didn't work and provided error code `-2146232060`. Error: `Logon failed for login '<<user>>' due to trigger execution. Changed database context to '<<DbName>>'. Changed language setting to us_english.`